# A form with variable number of inputs with Zend Form

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-form

I need to create a form that accepts a variable number of transactions. The form has 4 elements and an array of transactions(defined by: type(cr/dr), date, ledger(dropdown) and amount).
There can be any number of transsactions:this is handled by javasript and sent as a post array. Clearly Zend Forms isn't equipped to deal with this. How do I accept an infinite number of inputs with Zend Form?

Answer (score 2):

Following links will help you:

1. http://www.jeremykendall.net/2009/01/19/dynamically-adding-elements-to-zend-form/
2. [Initializing a zend form with variable data length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620827/initializing-a-zend-form-with-variable-data-length)
3. http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Form.Fieldset.html (Fieldset tag is used to Group related elements in a form)

Comment: the first link is actually helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have to create all 4 form fields to array type by writing

**isArray=>true**

by using this your form field name like type[],date[],ledger[] and amount[].
and you got all values in controller after form post.

These element are like array.now you can do anything that you want.